# Line of code not working unless stepped through using breakpoint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The only thing I can think of is a race condition but both the calling function and the line of code are synchronous to my knowledge.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the log format string for an info-level log.
/// </summary>
public static string Info<T>(string action, T obj)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(String.Format(
        "Action: {0} \tObject: {1} \tUser: {2} \tJson: ",
        action, typeof(T).Name, User
    ));

    // Set all virtual properties to null. This should stop circular references of navigation properties.
    var virtualProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => x.GetSetMethod().IsVirtual && !x.PropertyType.IsPrimitive);
    foreach (var propInfo in virtualProperties)
    {
        propInfo.SetValue(obj, null); // This Line is the culprit.
    }

    GetJsonSerializer().Serialize(obj, stringBuilder);

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

The line `propInfo.SetValue(obj, null)` will execute if I just breakpoint before the loop and step through one-by-one (or just break on that line) however if I don't use a breakpoint it never sets the property(ies) to null. Why is this?

**Specific Details**:

- If I don't use a breakpoint it doesn't work.
- If I place a breakpoint at the top of the foreach and hit f5 it doesn't work.
- If I place a breakpoint at the top of the foreach and step-through via f10 it does work.
- If I place a breakpoint on the line of code `propInfo.SetValue(obj, null);` it does work.
- A breakpoint after the loop still shows the values as not null.
- If I change `null` to `5` (which isn't a valid value) it throws an exception telling my that it's not a valid value.

To clarify, *"Doesn't work"* means that it doesn't set the property to null.

**What I've tried:**

- Restarting Visual Studio (2013)
- Changing the line of code (Used to be `default(T)`)
- Project Properties -> Build -> Optimize Code (initially off)

**EDIT**

It's been narrowed down that EF Navigation properties are the cause of this behavior. The code is running but for some reason the navigation properties refuse to become null. So what about navigation properties are causing this behavior?

Comment: What is happening, if anything to obj before you pass it in?

Comment: I'm submitting it for edit. It gets saved to database via EF. Then I pass it to this to serialize and log. I can't imagine anything before this would affect it given the circumstances but I guess anything is possible. After this function log4net saves the log entry to the database.

Comment: What happens if you try non-EF `T` types? Maybe it's possible that entity framework isn't "accepting" the property change and we might be able to pin down that reason.

Comment: Okay so, that last "detail" makes me think that the issue has to do with the properties I'm setting being Navigation Properties in Entity Framework. But I'm not sure why this behavior would appear.

Comment: @31eee384 The thing is though, that loop is 100% targetting EF navigation properties and has no other purpose than to set them to null. Finds non-primitive virtual properties so that circular references don't happen. When I was including the primitive values instead of null) I'm pretty certain it was setting that value. I'll double check though.

Comment: Indeed, the primitive virtual property is being changed. Just not the EF navigational properties. I guess I'll add an EF tag to the question.

Comment: To be more concrete, I'm suggesting creating a new, non-EF class with non-primitive virtual properties, initializing it, and passing it into this function. This could even be a unit test. If it works for those and not for EF, then I'd say it's deeply EF related (even though it makes no sense!)

Comment: Yeah, it's an EF Navigation Property thing. Non-EF virtual non-primitive gets set to null.

Comment: It's the lazy loading. Doing a GetValue before the SetValue made it work. I'm still curious on an explanation for this though. I don't 100% understand what's going on even though I'm pretty sure I know why now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Lazy-Loading**

The navigation properties were lazy-loading, so when the serializer looked at them they got overwritten by the original value. So the setting of null was working the whole time but was getting overwritten by the lazy-loading.

**Debugging**

The reason the debugging appeared the way it did was because I was looking at the value before I executed the SetValue line of code. This caused the navigation property to load the value before executing the line of code resulting in the null value not being overwritten.

**Solution**

```
foreach (var propInfo in virtualProperties)
{
    propInfo.GetValue(obj); // Trigger any navigation property to load.
    propInfo.SetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Comment: Just curious, would adding a .All() or .ToList() selector to the end of typeof(T).GetProperties(...) force the collection to enumerate and load all items?

Comment: `.ToList()` added to the `typeof(T).GetProperties()...` would not force the loading. This is because this is on the properties collection and not the properties themselves. I tested to confirm my suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

I had a VERY similar issue in a Many-to-many EF6 code first setup. In my Web API controller I had been setting an object's navigation property from values set from a DTO. One being passed into my repo, they properties weren't being updated because of the lazy loading, but in debug mode it would work if I stepped near that section of code. I ended up using:

```
try {
    TheDatabase.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    ...
    ...
}
finally {
    TheDatabase.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}
```

This appears to be working so far.. Since my dbContext is being disposed per controller, I don't think it will be an issue.